# Why cannot an implicitly typed variable be declared at class level?

Tags: c#, type-inference, var

So the code below is perfectly valid and it outputs 5 as excpected and the type of `foo` is inferred as `System.Int32`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = 5;
       Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
}
```

But if you write something like this

```
class Program
{
    static var foo = 5;

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
}
```

you get the following error:

> The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration.

What is the problem of declaring variable using the `var`-keyword at class level? I don't quite understand this, so can anybody make it clear?

Comment: take a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx

Comment: in short, because they can't. Definite duplicate I say.

Comment: Its like the general question, "why doesn't this thing do this thing that I want?" and the answer is, "because nobody made it do it yet." Followed by some detailed explanation of how difficult that it is.

Comment: So this site is running out of space or what ?? What if it is a duplicate why you care if questions are duplicate ?and i don't find it duplicate with question in reference but actually question referred is the answer for this question .Do not take advantages of privileges you got and please provide some answer also .